# Custom taxonomy suddenly redirects to another page

Tags: wordpress

I stumbled upon a weird problem today, and I need some pointers for where I can look for the source of the problem. This has also happened briefly one time before, with no apparent changes to the site beforehand. It is a WordPress install with WooCommerce. I know it's hard to troubleshoot like this, but if anyone has any pointers what so ever, I would be immensely grateful.

We suddenly found our custom taxonomy "brand" (for the WooCommerce product custom post type) redirected to other pages matching the name, much like WordPress does when you have a typo in the URL.

`/brand/brand-name/` was suddenly redirecting to `/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/brand-name.png`, and `/brand/other-brand/` was suddenly redirecting to `/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/other-brand.mp4`.

This happened regardless of clicking a link to the brand on the site, or visiting it directly in incognito mode in the browser. I contacted my host, and they say redirections are not cached, so this was generated on the fly from PHP or other code. It was just like the taxonomy did not exist, and WordPress was trying to help with redirecting to a page matching the name.

I went into my permalinks and saved them, and the error suddenly disappeared. I have no idea how to provoke it or where I should start looking for the cause. The taxonomy is registered in the file `functions.php` like this:

```
// Add brand taxonomy to products
function so_brand_tax()
{
    register_taxonomy('brand', array('product'), array(
        'label'        => 'Brands',
        'rewrite'      => array('slug' => 'brands', 'hierarchical' => true),
        'hierarchical' => true
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'so_brand_tax', 0);
```

The permalink structure is set to custom, and then just `/%postname%/`.

This is something that I have noticed only once before, and the problem disappeared with saving permalinks. I don't like having things like this happen and not being able to explain to anyone why they are happening and what I am doing to solve the problem. This is a pretty serious error based on the amount of money spent on ads to these exact pages per month.

There had been no plugin updates or other major changes before any of the two events, at least that I know of.

What could I do next?

Comment: Rename those files or at least change the permalink to those files. That's how you fix it. If you have a file with the same name as a page slug, WP will get confused about where those URLs should go to, since internally, WP will try to guess the correct redirect. To future proof this, you can use a filter that when any media file gets uploaded, you can prefix or add a suffix, like `-image` or `-video` to the file name/slug. Edit: this isn't a Woocommerce issue, this will happen with any post type.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct, though? If the taxonomy exists and is set, there is no reason to guess anything. The URL directs to the taxonomy. And it does, in 99.9 % of all cases. Then suddenly it's like the taxonomy disappears, and then WordPress needs to guess. Renaming the files like you suggest will just send the users to a 404 page if no pages or files match.

Comment: It is correct. You are essentially creating two URLs with the same slug. That's why resetting the permalinks works temporarily. You would have to do mitigation for your files that are already uploaded. That's why I offered a future solution to this issue, or you will continue to run into it.

Comment: It's not the same slug, though? /brands/brand-name/ is not the same as /uploads/2020/03/brand-name.png. How can /uploads/ be the same as /brands/ in WordPress' eyes? That would be beyond bad programming. Are you sure you read the question correctly? By that logic, a web designer that has a site with the page /services/logo/ would have their page redirected to /uploads/2020/03/logo.png that shows their site logo as an image? I can't think that would be the case.

Comment: Yes, I read the question correctly. I've run into this exact same problem in the many years I've been developing WP sites. I'm giving you a direction to try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look into it some more! It just seems like a very bad programming decision if that's the case. It's a site with 10 000 products and probably 300 000 media files. There is no way to control that no one uploads a file with the same name as a brand across all the possible file upload sites on the system...

Comment: _There is no way to control that no one uploads a file with the same name as a brand_ Exactly. That's why with large sites like that, I would implement a filter to basically rename the slug/file name on upload. Appending `-image` or even a random hash is a good way to go about it. Saves headaches down the road.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on this phenomenon? I can't find any.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165651/post-slugs-and-images-cannot-have-same-name/165658

Comment: Thank you, it's starting to make more sense now. We of course have Yoast installed, and that redirects media pages directly to their image file. That "hid" the double permalinks from my brains logic processor. I take it that choosing the radio button "Post name" is the same as %postname% and won't change a thing? But then again, we have the front "/brands/" before "/brand-name/" shouldn't that stop WordPress from thinking we want to access domain.com/brand-name/? We want to access domain.com/brands/brand-name/, so it should not be a problem?

Comment: I can see that this would be a problem if I created a post named /brand-name/, but this is a taxonomy that has a front to it in the URL. I therefore don't see the link that was posted as the same problem as this, since the slugs actually are different. It also does not explain how this could happen suddenly without any explanation on both brands and images that have been static for months and months. But truly, thanks for donating your time on this issue. I will report back if I ever uncover the reason for this, whatever it might be.